# Deducing proportionality from this differential equation

Tags: general-relativity

I am reading a paper in which the author is deducing from the following differential equation
$$\dot{v} + \Big(\frac{\dot{a}}{a} + \frac{\dot{f_2}}{f_2}\Big)(1-v^2)v = 0, $$ that $$\frac{v}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} \propto (af_2)^{-1}.$$
For context, $a$ represents the scale factor in FRW spacetime and $v$ is the velocity of a $0-$brane in $1+1$ dimensions; $f_2 = f_2(R)$ is a function of the scalar curvature. I cannot see how to show this is true. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try differentiating $\ln (a f_2 v/\sqrt{1-v^2})   $.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks, that solves my problem.

Comment: If your problem is solved then please write an answer and accept it so the system has a way to know it's closed and other users can find the answer if they look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an arbitrary constant *c*, 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\ln ~ ( c~ a~ f_2 ~ \frac{v}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} ) = 
\frac {\dot{a}} {a} + \frac {\dot{f_2}} {f_2} + \frac {\dot{v}} {v(1-v^2)} ~,
$$
so the zero of the r.h.s. dictates
$$
\frac{C}{a~ f_2} =  \frac{v}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} ~~,
$$
for some constant *C*.